# ASP.NET MVC form post with special character

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I am doing a basic form post for a login page, we are running into problems with special character just `<!` and `&#`. I wanted to see if there is a way to fix that in the form post?

I tried setting the `charset="UTF-8"` but I am still having the problem.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
```

Comment: There is some info missing, but maybe add `[AllowHtml]` attibute to the password property in the model?